# How to save checkbox selection having same name and id

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am looking out for logic how to create relationship between child element selected with its parent to differentiate on server to know that option is selected under particular parent.

**e.g.** In my following question i wanted to know that `Math` is selected under which parent (Andy, John or Murray) on server side.

I have the following code

```
    <li ng-repeat="student in Students">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="{{student[0].Id + $index + $parent.$index}}"/>
    <label for="{{student[0].Id+ $index + $parent.$index}}"><span class="Radiobox-txt" id="{{student[0].Name}}">{{student[0].Name}}</span></label>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="subject in student.Subjects">
            <input type="checkbox" id="{{subject.Id+ $index + $parent.$index}}" ng-model="subject.Checked" />
            <label for="{{subject.Id+ $index + $parent.$index}}"><span id="{{subject.Name}}">{{subject.Name}}</span></label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

The above code generates UI like following with checkbox option showing with each:

```
Andy
    Math
    English
    Computer
John
    Math
    English
    Computer
Murray
    Math
    English
    Computer
```

Currently, the following is my code where i am pushing selected child's Id into array.

Probably i need to modify this code to also push parent Id along with child Id so on server i can know the relationship but not sure whether to concatenate parentId or some other way around. **Idea please?**

```
$scope.studentDetail.PermissionIds = [];
angular.forEach($scope.permissions, function (p) {
var selectedPermissions = $filter('filter')(p.Children, { Checked: true });
for (var i in selectedPermissions) {
$scope.studentDetail.PermissionIds.push(selectedPermissions[i].Id);
```

Comment: Use `classes`. HTML `id`s must be unique.

Answer (score 0):

Use student.id rather than student [0].id. I'm guessing that is unique?